# Conflict between getBoundingClientRect and position Relative

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

In my Javascript code, I have this variable :
let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

This variable is necessary do display a Canvas in a modal.

But on my HTML page, I have a slider (diaporama) with relative position.
And since I have this relative position, my Canvas is not displayed in my mdodal.

CSS for my diaporama :

```
#diaporama {
    position: relative;

}
```

Part of my Javascript with getBoundingClientRect :

```
class Signature {
  constructor() {
    this.color = "#000000";
    this.sign = false;
    this.begin_sign = false;
    this.width_line = 5;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.offsetLeft = this.canvas.offsetLeft;
    this.offsetTop = this.canvas.offsetTop;
    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
    this.whenMouseDown();
    this.whenMouseUp();
    this.whenMouseMove();
    this.createSignature();
    this.clearCanvas();
    this.resetCanvas();
  }

  updateMousePosition(mX, mY) {
    let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let scaleX = this.canvas.width / rect.width;
    let scaleY = this.canvas.height / rect.height;
    this.cursorX = (mX - rect.left) * scaleX;
    this.cursorY = (mY - rect.top) * scaleY;
  }
```

You can see the HTML page here :
http://p4547.phpnet.org/bikes/index.html

How can I keep my position relative and make my Signature canvas works ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

I edited the JS code like this :

```
    updateMousePosition(mX, mY) {
        let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // renvoie la taille d'un élément et sa position relative par rapport à la zone d'affichage (viewport)
        let left   = rect.left   + window.scrollX;
      let top    = rect.top    + window.scrollY;
        let scaleX = this.canvas.width / rect.width;
        let scaleY = this.canvas.height / rect.height;
        this.cursorX = (mX - left) * scaleX;
        this.cursorY = (mY - top) * scaleY;
    }
```